# Why is type or ref required for layer in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

mapbox-gl-js throws an error if a layer does not have a type. However, type is optional in the spec, and ref is not mentioned in the spec (was apparently taken out at some point). Can somebody clarify this? Should type be required then for the layer in the spec? Or something else?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the documentation is out of date. `type` should not be `optional` now that `ref` has been deprecated. `type` should be required.

The [style spec docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layer-type) read:

> `type`
>   Optional enum. One of `"fill"`, `"line"`, `"symbol"`, `"circle"`, `"heatmap"`, `"fill-extrusion"`, `"raster"`, `"background"`.

Comment: Agreed, do you want me to ticket this in github?